# Maching Most Suitabale names with compaireing 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql tables:

```
Customers(id,short_name,full_name, contact, address, amount)

old_customer_record(id, name, contact, address, amount)
```

And this case I have above 2000 records and I want to confirm all of old customers are includes in new table.

But I can't  get directly check because,

- some spelling mistakes or bit diffrents like,
  **N.IDUNIL RANGAJEEWA** in old and ***N. INDUNIL RANGAJEEWA*** as new one
  same as contact numbers like, **071-1234567** and **0711234567**
- amounts may be updated in new table.
- address in old table not complete in old one like, **Somewhere,SomeProvince** and **123/B,Somewhere,SomeProvince**

What I want to do for that ? or is it possible? 
And my code is as follow,

```
for ($i=1; $i < 2000; $i++) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM old_customers WHERE id = '$i'";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array();

    $name = $row[1];

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE  short_name LIKE '%$name%'";
    $result1 = $connect->query($sql1);
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_array()) {
        $output['data'][] = array(
               $row1[0],
               $row1[1],
               $row1[2],
               $row1[3],
               $row1[4]
             );
    }
  } // if num_rows
 }

echo json_encode($output);
```

Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: what about their account? do they login using an email address of some sort?

Comment: @Kevin No, they not login into system and only maintain a records. this is for like loan amount records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose what column fits best to compare tables. I see `name` and `contact` most suitable for that. `Address` may have different forms and amounts may be the same for many records (is not unique).
2. Sanitize phone numbers in both tables.

   - remove spaces, `-` and other not needed chars
   - check length of numbers, if it is too short add leading zero or proper area code for Sri Lanka.
3. Compare two tables on phone numbers. Check these records which don't exist in old table and check them manually looking for similar name etc. 2000 records is still not big number. You probably will check small number, like 20. But I'm not sure about structure and content of your table.

Comment: It is really help me because "Sanitize phone numbers in both tables."